# Suggestions on a solution for storing photos per client, which they can then have access to

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am trying to build an app for a photographer.  These are his requirements:

- Photographer can upload photos or files (files up to 20-30mb).
- Photographer can categorize photos and files by client.
- Photographer can create client username and passwords.
- Photographer can send email from web interface to link to download. (which requires client login)
- Client can login and view and download photos and files assigned to his account.
- Photographer mentioned **1-2 terabytes** of data needs to be stored.

So, my questions:

- Is there an open source system out there that already does this.
- Is there an app already out there that does this. Photographer currently uses "yousendit" but the free solution is not sufficient since data is lost after 2 weeks.
- He mentioned he could host it on a box at his office, but his connection is limited.. thaughts?  At that point storage space would not be an issue.  I would have to code this app.
- GoDaddy hosting for example does unlimited storage with one of its plans that is reasonable.  If I coded my own app, this would be perfect.  I do hate GoDaddy though..
- I will listen to any alternative suggestions.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about building an app like this, but [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/photos/photo-sharing-features/) is an existing app that hits most of your requirements.

- Can upload unlimited JPGs as part of base cost, other files can be uploaded at additional cost
- Photos can be categorized into galleries per client.
- Galleries can be locked down, with clients getting unique user/pass to their gallery
- Not 100% sure if you can email a link directly from the site, but I believe you can.
- Additionally, if you get a pro account, clients can order prints online (no need to build your own payment processing), you can "theme" the galleries how you like, automatic watermarking, etc.

The base cost is $40-$150/year, depending on what level you choose, plus whatever you need for additional file storage.  Not sure if it meets all your needs, but just throwing it out there.  Note: I am not affiliated w/ SmugMug, just a satisfied user.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you need to answer is whether you will store the files in the database or on the file system. Given the amount of data in question, I would store the file on the file system and keep meta data about the files including their location in the database. The catch to this approach is that you have to keep the two in sync with each other. It is not particularly difficult to build that system.

The second question relates to where you store the files. You could store the at the same place where you host the site or you could use a cloud storage option like Amazon's S3 (or DreamHOst mentioned by J_B). One advantage of using cloud storage is that the site can hosted anywhere without affecting the location of the files.

Comment: I was definitely thinking about going the File System with Database Meta Data route.  My only concern with Amazon's S3 is that I am looking at paying $200.00 a month for storage if I have 2 terabytes that need stored.  This is why Dreamhost or GoDaddy with unlimited storage would be a good option.

Comment: Another question I have is having a file stored in something like Amazon's S3, how do I prevent someone with unauthorized access downloading a picture if they have the url?

Comment: S3, like most storage services, has various access control settings to cover such needs.

Answer (score 0):

[DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?578620) might not mind.  They say they will give you all the storage your site needs with all plans (+ some extra for storing whatever you want).

I don't know about an app that does that.  Doesn't sound REAL hard to write.

Comment: well it looks like dreamhost isnt the solution. in the fine print they mention it cannot be used as a file repository, which i guess it kind of is.

Comment: I suppose it could be.. it is kind of an extreme amount of data.. but it is a web app for a client, and not like... a warez file host.  It wouldn't hurt to ask, just because I don't like a lot of godaddy.